# Why influxDB discourages/depreciate the use of Web Admin Interface (GUI) starting from 1.2?

Tags: influxdb

As quote from the documentation:

> The built-in web administration GUI is deprecated in InfluxDB 1.2 and is disabled by default. We recommend using the HTTP API or the Command Line Interface to interact with InfluxDB.

Why does it encourage using HTTP API (HTTP method) and CLI, instead of the intuitive Web GUI? What is the benefit of applying this?

Comment: They have [chronograf](https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf) which has gui admin features.

Answer (score 4):

The old admin interface is removed in 1.3 since it was largely undeveloped internally. Instead, we've moved all that functionality and much more to [Chronograf](https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.3/). Going forward that's where all UI for the various parts of the stack will live. It's also open source.

Comment: Actually not quite everything! In the old UI I was able to view the data in UTC time but not in Chronograph thou. It forcefully updated the time to match my local browser's timezone :(